# Avoid default services in Service Fabric?

Tags: azure-service-fabric

On the Service Fabric community Q&A today, one of the team members seemed to recommend not using default services. Is there some documentation which would elaborate on this further? Most importantly though, if there are no default services, how do any services get created, or is the implication that you'll need at least one default service which dynamically creates the rest?

Comment: Is there a recording of it?

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/premier_developer/2017/08/15/how-not-to-use-service-fabric-default-services/

Answer (score 1):

> Is there some documentation which would elaborate on this further?

There is not official documentation about it, most of the places talking about it will be found on these Q&A.

> if there are no default services, how do any services get created, or is the implication that you'll need at least one default service which dynamically creates the rest?

On service fabric, you have two options to  create your services:

- The **Declarative** way, done via Default Services feature where you describe services that should run as part of your application using the ApplicationManifest.
- and the **Dynamic**(Imperative) way using powershell commands to create these services once the application is deployed.

I've given an extensive answer about it on another SO question here: 
[Auto creation of Service without DefaultServices on developer machines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50441340/auto-creation-of-service-without-defaultservices-on-developer-machines/50445801#50445801)